# Edit color profile (.icc) to change gamma

Tags: xorg, color-management

As a lot of other users here on Ask Ubuntu, I need to use xrandr to correct the gamma settings on one of my external monitors. Settings applied this way aren't permanent and they can reset basically randomly (for me).

Would it be possible to somehow edit the default color profile of my monitor and just change the gamma value, then reimport it into Gnome color configuration utility? I don't have access to specialized calibration equipment.

Comment: Did you find a way (apart from putting the xrandr command in a .profile of some kind)?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. :(